# Does javascript execute if no function is called?

Tags: javascript, performance, wordpress

I have some wordpress pages with javascript code that require javascript file references.  For pages that don't call functions within these js file references, there should be no performance impact for including these files (except the file call) right?

-- EDIT in response to @cdhowie --

If only certain pages require these javascript files, is it possible to move them out of the head section and into the page?  I've read this is bad practice.

But in theory, this prevents the entire site from having a performance hit for files that are not being utilized?

Comment: If a tree falls in a forest, and there's no one around to hear it, does it make a sound?

Comment: @Ian In this case, yes.

Comment: @cdhowie I didn't hear anything.

Comment: @Ian But the browser did. :)

Comment: So did the visitor that clicked away.

Comment: @cdhowie Aw shucks, foiled again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript functions are only executed when you explicitly call them (or implicitly in callbacks and whatnot).  The code will however still be interpreted by the browser on each page regardless of functions being called or not.

Edit:
I was wrong to say the performance hit is irrelevant.  It really all depends on your exact situation (where the code is coming from, how much code, etc.) and also how much you care about performance in terms of milliseconds.

One possible "performance" issue is if those extra .js files are on your server. If so and you are loading them when it is not needed, you are causing for unneeded traffic and bandwidth in regards to your server.

Comment: Just so I understand, you are disagreeing with @cdhowie's response?

Comment: No actually I agree with what he is saying.  Our answers kind of refer to two separate things.  I am just saying that If you include Javascript code in a file, yet never explicitly call any of the functions included in that code, you would receive worst performance than if you never included the code.  However, I am saying this performance hit is very minimal.  Also, I am referring to the fact you are putting unneeded load on your server if you are loading in a file that you do not need.

Comment: @DevinLynch But I think that including a reference to an external Javascript file (and not even using it) is the biggest performance hit possible...because it has to make a separate HTTP request and load a (possibly) big file, which also has to be interpreted, and do nothing with it. Networking is usually the bottleneck, not browsers. If the code were inline in the HTML, then it wouldn't be as big of a burden because there's no separate HTTP request.

Comment: @Devin: cdhowie is saying the contents of the external file will be executed (not just parsed), even if there is no in page js calling functions in the file.  But you are saying that is not the case.  You are saying the file will only be parsed.  I believe you are in disagreement with what cdhowie is saying...unless you both mean executed == parsed???

Comment: @4thSapce: if cdhowie is saying an enclosed function is executed even if it is not explicitly or implicitly called somewhere in your code, then yes I am disagreeing with him.  I think he is talking about global code when I am talking about encapsulated code since you mentioned "call functions" in your question

Comment: @Devin: what difference does global or function make if both are in PageA.html?  My example is the entire site vs just the specific page(s) with js that references a file.  So if PageB.html has no in page js, then nothing is executed in the external files (but David is saying it still does execute...I disagree also).  If you load some massive js file (all functions) and nothing calls those functions, they will not execute.  It's just the weight of that page plus parsing.

Comment: @4thSpace:  Correct, if you load a file containing only function definitions/declarations, the code within them will not execute assuming they are not called in any other JS file.

Comment: @Devin: Cool.  But if they are not in functions, you are saying (global) code will still execute?  For code in functions of an ext file, does it still even parse that?

Comment: @4thSpace:  All Javascript code will be parsed regardless of scope.  To demonstrate, include a file that has a syntax error encapsulated in a function, and then look at your Javascript console.

Answer (score 3):

The referenced JavaScript files will be downloaded (or fetched from the cache) and then be executed by the browser's JavaScript interpreter in both cases.  The "JavaScript file references" need to be executed in order to create the variables and functions that you might use, and the browser has no way of knowing ahead of time if you will use them.  Further, the included files might actually manipulate the document, and the browser doesn't know this either until it has executed them.

So yes, there will be a performance impact whether or not you call the functions.  Whether or not it's significant enough for you to worry about is something you will have to determine.  (Always profile your page's loading time before making decisions like this!)

Comment: but as long as you do not call the functions, you should be okay (for the most part)

Comment: @4thSpace The rule for external linkage in HTML is "declare your CSS links as high as possible in the page, and your JavaScript as low as possible in the page." Your script tags should come *at the very end* of the document in either case, right before `</body>` -- first the libraries you need, and then your own JavaScript files/code.

Comment: What it if your js in the page doesn't execute when you move the js file reference to the bottom of the page?

Comment: @cdhowie if your script is just a couple of lines and you don't care about page load times - in the millisecond or lower range for a few lines of code (which most people don't), then you should be okay. 4thSpace once you have a script tag as part of your page, it will always be read by the JavaScript interpreter even though you may not call the function. It's like carrying your wallet with you, even though you may not call the creditcard, cash or driverslicence functions in a particular day, it still contributes to your weight.

Comment: @4thSpace Then you put them in the wrong order. Your scripts should always be at the bottom, after the libraries you need.  Your code should not be intermixed with page content; that's just silly.

Comment: @ebadedude Apparently you missed the final paragraph of my answer, where I said almost exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

This will execute, but take up very little cpu time

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   // just a comment
</script>
```

no functions, just a comment... but it's still "code", still has to be parsed, still has to be checked for syntax errors, etc...